# What is the ajax url if

Tags: magento-1.9, url, ajax

help, what will be the ajax url if
method is in: 
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CmsBlockController.php ?

Comment: do you want to access it from admin Or front ?

Comment: did you mean  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php ?

Comment: From admin, from front i think it wouldnt be a problem

Comment: Yes Satish, this is the controller I wouldlike to use "/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php"

Answer (score 1):

If your admin controller path is `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php`

Then your url would be: `admin/adminhtml/cms/block/ACTION`

Comment: Thank you R.Jensen, this is what I wanted :)

Comment: Not sure if there is any additional action required to make it work or ... how can I make sure if the method I developed works ? There is no errors displayed, Magento is not crashing when trying to call the method but I can't find if it actually do anything :(

Comment: Is your controller action sending a response? Or are you being redirected to a 404 page?

Comment: Actually it does not sending back anything just updating (in theory) some values, that's it, but it seems not receiving anything as the log is not created. Added a Mage::log('test','mylog.log'); as a first line in controller to make sure it is called.

Comment: i was trying some other urls and sometimes i was getting action not allowed or something like this.

Comment: Are you logged in as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, operating as an administrator.

Comment: You should be able to access all routes, can you update your question with your full path to the controller, the config.xml and your action?

Comment: Wait, one sec, I tried on core files (copied into the local - keeping of course structure) and saveAction works (extended slightly to upload images etc) and it works so the controller itself is perfectly fine. In the same controller added  new method and using ajax (jQuery) trying to send some extra data to this method. Just to make it completely clear. So either the url is wrong or .... new method must be somehow registered ? or ?

Comment: OK, my module is now ready, controller rewrite works now .... the url for my Ajax if controller is :/app/code/local/Amber/SupaSlid/controllers/Adminhtml/Cms/BlockController.php what should be the url  to call action reorder ?

Comment: The url should still be `admin/adminhtml/cms/block/ACTION` is your method suffixed by the word 'action' ? Your method should be named something like this: public function ajaxAction()

Comment: Hello R.Jensen, and it does :( will try  some other ways but i would love to see it working "Magento" way :)